# Let $s_{nn}=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_ib_j$, prove that the limit of it is $AB$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, double-sequence

THe problem first assumed that

> $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lvert a_i\rvert=A,\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\lvert b_j\rvert=B$

It then asked me to prove:

> $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\lvert a_ib_j\rvert$ converges

I did it. Now I am stuck in the problem.

> $s_{nn}=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_ib_j$, prove that the limit of it is $AB$

I approached it in several ways

1. Directly prove $s_{nn}$ converges to AB, but to no avail
2. Prove $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_ib_j$ converges to AB, but to no avail
3. Prove $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_ib_j=(\sum_{i=1}^na_i)(\sum_{j=1}^nb_j)$, but then I am unable to prove the latter converges to $AB$.

I don't have a clue as to how to approach this now. The square summation is already a headache since it has $n^2$ term instead of the standard $n$ terms in series.

Edit 1: This is the problem from the book. I hope my translation to latex is accurate. In addition, this is copied from the same book yet different version. But it still gets the gist.

[image: Edit 1: This is adapted from the same book yet different version. But it still has the gist.]

Edit 2: The definition of absolute convergence by the book.

[image: definition of absolute convergence]

Comment: There must be an error. If $a_1=-1=-b_1$ and $a_i=b_i=0$ for $i>2$, then $A=B=1$ but $s_{nn}=-1\not\to 1=AB$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: @plop This is weird since this is a question from Steven Abbott's Understanding Analysis. It is possible that I typed it wrong. I will try to put screenshot into the post.

Comment: They say that $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely to $A$, but they mean by that that $\sum |a_n|$ is convergent and $\sum a_n=A$, rather than $\sum |a_n|=A$.

Comment: @plop I was always under the impression that $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely means $\sum |a_n|=A$. The reason is because of the definition, as attached, in the book. Am I misinterpreting the book?

Comment: "$\sum a_n$ converges absolutely" means that $\sum |a_n|$ is convergent. But in that book, with the phrase "$\sum a_n$ converges absolutely to $A$", they clearly mean what I said above. That makes the result true and it is false otherwise.

Comment: @zony_miu:  yes, you are misinterpreting it.  Take the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n2^{-n}$.  It is a geometric series with ratio $-\frac 12$, so converges.  The sum is $\frac 1{1-(-\frac 12)}=\frac 23$.  The sum of the absolute values of the terms is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n}=2$.  The fact that the sum of the absolute values is finite allows all sorts of theorems, like any rearrangement sums to the same value.

Comment: Thank you all. I will start reworking the questions and till then if I am stuck again I will ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on new assumption, I yield the following solution.

\begin{align}
\forall n\in\mathbb{N}s_{nn}&=(\sum_{i=1}^na_i)(\sum_{j=1}^nb_j)\\
\rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}s_{nn}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sum_{i=1}^na_i)(\sum_{j=1}^nb_j)\\
&=(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i)(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_j)\\
&=AB
\end{align}

Edit: Since no one objects, I will take it as my solution. :)